# How to re-alloc an array

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to refill an NsMutableArray as follows.I am wondering if there's any safety problems in this way. thanks in advance!

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool 
    {

        NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:4];
        [myArray addObject:@"something1"];
        [myArray addObject:@"something2"];
        [myArray addObject:@"something3"];
        [myArray addObject:@"something4"];

    myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:3];
        [myArray addObject:@"somethingNew1"];
        [myArray addObject:@"somethingNew2"];
        [myArray addObject:@"somethingNew3"];

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what makes you believe that there could be a problem?

Comment: The problem is that the array is referred to as both `myArray` and `muArray`, so clearly this is not real code - since if it were, it wouldn't even compile.

Comment: worried that the array elements wont be safety released

Comment: sry for the bad typing

Comment: The array elements are all `@"string"` objects, and these ignore proper retain/release semantics anyway. They exist forever. If your array had regular objects in it, we might have something to discuss.

Comment: Perhaps this question would be more suitable for codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Code review question, should be on CodeReview@SE

Answer (score 2):

[myArray removeAllObjects];

// add stuff

Comment: This is a decent optimization but it doesn't make the code any more or less safe.

Answer (score 1):

This looks okay to me.

- If you're using ARC, it's all done for you.
- If you're using manual refcounting, well, you never retain anything, so it's all freed once the `autorelease` scope closes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:]` is not really necessary. Just `alloc` and
`init` will do the trick. From here, you can just add objects and it will automatically resize. Using the `-removeAllObjects` method will clear your array and safely release all objects. After that, just add anything new you want with `-addObject:`.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool 
    {

        NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [myArray addObject:@"something1"];
        [myArray addObject:@"something2"];
        [myArray addObject:@"something3"];
        [myArray addObject:@"something4"];

        [myArray removeAllObjects];
        [myArray addObject:@"somethingNew1"];
        [myArray addObject:@"somethingNew2"];
        [myArray addObject:@"somethingNew3"];

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using `arrayWithCapacity:` is more efficient if you know how many elements will be in the array.

Comment: If you know you are going to be changing the array and changing its capacity, like the question does, just a normal `[[alloc] init]` will do the job. I agree though, specifying the capacity will be more efficient.